# connecting to mysql with java

Tags: java, mysql

i have written my first program but in output i cant see any thing. i create my table in mysql.

```
import java.sql.Connection; 
import java.sql.DriverManager; 
import java.sql.ResultSet; 
import java.sql.Statement; 


public class tester {

    public tester() {
    }
   public static void main(String[] args)  {


    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
    String user = "root"; 
    String pass = "123456"; 

    Connection connection = null; 
    Statement statement = null; 
    ResultSet resultSet = null; 
ResultSet rs;
    try { 
     Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); 
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection( 
        "jdbc:mysql://./test", user, pass); 
     statement = connection.createStatement(); 
     resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  student"); 
     rs = statement.getResultSet();
        while (rs.next()) {            
           System.out.print(rs.getString("sname")+("\t")) ;
           System.out.print(rs.getString("sfamily")+("\t")) ;
           System.out.print(rs.getString("saddress")+("\t")) ;
        }
     rs.close();
     statement.close();
     connection.close();

    } catch (Exception e) { 
}
   }
}
```

in my output i have: 
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
i cant see my records. what shall i do?
i add mysql-connector-java-5.1.18 in my project.

Comment: It seems that you have build your program but didnt run it?

Comment: Do you have data in that table ?

Comment: why you're using two resultset object you can use only one resultset object to retrieving the data from the database, try with the rs = statement.executeQuery() and put next line in comment i.e. rs=statement.getResultSet();

Comment: i have data in my table. and i run the program.

Comment: Please check if the connection has been established, if it has, i think GPS provides the correct answer. And, as naresh suggested, you shouldn't swallow the exception, just print the exception message.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're not getting any exceptions because you're not printing them. Change this part:

```
} catch (Exception e) { 
}
```

to this:

```
} catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I suspect the problem would be with the connection string here:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://./test", user, pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try with the following code**

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",user,pass);
 statement = connection.createStatement();
 resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  student");
 while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.print(resultSet.getString("sname")+("\t")) ;
        System.out.print(resultSet.getString("sfamily")+("\t")) ;
        System.out.print(resultSet.getString("saddress")+("\t")) ;
 }
```

**And ADD THIS to catch block**

```
catch (Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That's why you are not getting any exception.

**Suggestions**

1. You don't need two different result sets. You can do this way too :

   ```
   resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  student");
   while (resultSet.next()) {
      System.out.print(resultSet.getString("sname")+("\t")) ;
      System.out.print(resultSet.getString("sfamily")+("\t")) ;
      System.out.print(resultSet.getString("saddress")+("\t")) ;
   }
   ```
2. Close the connection, result set etc. in `finally` block.
3. Your class name should be `Tester` according to Java Naming Conventions.

Comment: @sami are you using IDE or running program from console ? are you getting any exception while running it ?

Comment: @sami try to replace your code with the code I wrote in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some IDE like eclipse? Else, compile and run the program as following:

```
javac tester.java
java tester
```

And in your catch clause do the following, instead of completely ignoring the exception:

```
catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i am using netbean. please help me. it is my first program in java. i am trying to learn.

Comment: go through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/netbeans.html to know how to build and run programs with netbeans IDE

Answer (score 0):

hey I think  this code works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ums1", user, pass);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.print(rs.getString(1) + ("\t"));
            System.out.print(rs.getString(2) + ("\t"));
            System.out.print(rs.getString(3) + ("\t"));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
            rs.close();
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

mind to change database url and table name. I tested with my one.

Comment: i didnot work. how can i be sure my program connect to mysql?

Comment: i add mysql-connector-java-5.1.18 to my project.

Comment: did you add the connector in your buildpath?

Comment: no, where is buildpath? i just add to library--- add jar files

Comment: are you using eclipse ? look this image : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44236198/buildpath.PNG

Answer (score 0):

1.You dont need two resultset.You can go below code.

```
import java.sql.Connection; 
import java.sql.DriverManager; 
import java.sql.ResultSet; 
import java.sql.Statement; 

//</editor-fold>
/**
 *
 * @author mohsen
 */
public class tester {

    public tester() {
    }
   public static void main(String[] args)  {


    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
    String user = "root"; 
    String pass = "123456"; 
    String dbUrl ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1";

    Connection connection = null; 
    Statement statement = null; 
   /* ResultSet resultSet = null; */
ResultSet rs =null;
    try { 
     Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); 
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, pass); 
     statement = connection.createStatement(); 
     rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  student"); 
   //  rs = statement.getResultSet();
        while (rs.next()) {            
           System.out.print(rs.getString("sname")+("\t")) ;
           System.out.print(rs.getString("sfamily")+("\t")) ;
           System.out.print(rs.getString("saddress")+("\t")) ;
        }
     rs.close();
     statement.close();
     connection.close();

    } catch (Exception e) { 

}
   }

}
```

2.Try to print Exception.So you got what is error in that.

3.Always close connection in finally.

Comment: It works dude i already tested and after i put it.You have to add one jar mysql.